# any way to remap keys for only one app?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I've seen the system wide tools (that all seem to just manipulate the default key bindings) that allow you to swap keys around, but has anyone found a way to swap keys for just one application? (no, the app in question doesn't offer it, and the author was a bit of a prick about it when I asked if they could enable an option to adjust them.)

I'm talking about real keys like home, end, page up, page down... not shortcuts.

Comment: is your question about redefining shortcuts for commands or "really" for keys as Nilloc understands your question?

Answer (score 2):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) might be your thing. Make a new command group which only applies to the application in question, then for each key you want to remap, make a new command with a hotkey trigger set to the real key and an "Insert Text" action set to what you want the key to be.

The *only* shortcoming I've found so far is that it can't handle the in-built volume control keys on an Apple keyboard. It can detect them & act upon the event, but it can't suppress the volume change. In fairness, nothing else can either. Most programs I tried can't even detect it. Keyboard Maestro is the king of the pile.

Comment: How can I make a new command group which only applies to a specific application? Is there any tutorial for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) for years and am constantly amazed at its flexibility. Despite its name, it is capable of intercepting/altering keyboard events as well, plus allows you to limit key mappings to particular applications.

Comment: Does BetterTouchTool has a free version?

Comment: @alper - read the page you edited out - it has links to the code for a free version as of 2018 - I don;t know if that runs on modern macOS

Comment: It does not run in `Big Sur` :-(

Comment: I'm running it right now on Big Sur without any issues, and the website has [an update from November 10, 2020](https://folivora.ai/blog/post/13015) stating that it fully supports Big Sur. @alper where did you read that Big Sur is not supported?

Comment: I had to update its version now it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to make your own keyboard layout, and switch to it when you open the application.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a menu item, you can create a custom shortcut in System Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts>Application Shortcuts. It lets you (re)assign any menu commands to whatever keyboard shortcut you want, for a specific app only.

Comment: I think the question was about remapping keys for example <kbd>d</kbd> would behave as <kbd>e</kbd> (if it were switched to a dvorak layout, not assigning shortcuts.

Comment: Nilloc is correct, this is about real keys.

Comment: There is no `Application Shortcuts` exist