# Can you remap keys to only be used while using VMware?

Tags: keyboard, vmware, parallels-desktop, keybindings

I've just started using VMware, and I am admittedly a novice Mac user. Anyways, I installed Windows 7 on my iMac, and I've been playing this little indie game that requires the use of the insert and home keys. My keyboard doesn't have those keys available.

Is there a way to remap keys so that they are only remapped within Windows? If not, what is my best option?

Comment: The answers to this earlier post might help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/any-way-to-remap-keys-for-only-one-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes, you can.

VMware Fusion (from v2) provides this built-in to the application (and incidentally Parallels provides almost identical functionality)

Under VMware Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse you can turn on/off the mapping of keys to other functions.

This [document](http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-4/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-5E971E88-DEB1-4A37-8245-401732CBACFA.html) over on VMware's document repository itemises how.

This [video over on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/1602305?pg=embed&sec=1602305) shows how it works in practice (the video shows it working in Fusion 2, but the functionality hasn't changed drastically since).